# How to Create multiple table from query based on multidimensional array

Tags: php, html

i dont know wheather this question already asked and answered it but i have search many things but did not get desired output of my problem

i have table like this

```
Name  |  desc    |    dep <br />
--------------------------------
abc   | content  | editing <br />
xyz   | content  | document <br />
pqr   | content  | marketing <br />
lcv   | content  | scripting <br />
khg   | content  | writer <br />
asd   | content  | finalize <br />
frt   | content  | checker <br />
```

in my php code i have created multidimensional array with single key with multiple values

```
$arr1 = array
        (
       'first' => array('abc','lcv','asd'),
       'second' => array('xyz','pqr','khg','frt')
);

$RowNumber=1; 
for ($row = 0; $row < count($arr1); $row++) { 
$cols = count($arr1[$row]); 
for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) { 
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tbl_data;"); 
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
echo '<tr>'; echo ' <td>'.$RowNumber.'</td> <td>'.$keyname.'</td> <td>'.$rows['Name'].'</td> <td>'.$rows['desc'].'</td> <td>'.$rows['dep'].'</td>'; echo '</tr>'; $RowNumber++; } } }
```

i want to create seperate table for each key 'first' with all three values similarly for next key but in new table and so on so my desired output will be look like this
'first' key table

```
  No  |   keyname   | Name   |  desc    |    dep <br />
--------------------------------------------------------
  1   |  first      |  abc   | content  | editing <br />
  2   |  first      |  lcv   | content  | scripting <br />
  3   |  first      |  asd   | content  | finalize <br />
```

'Second' key table

```
  No  |   keyname    | Name   |  desc    |    dep <br />
--------------------------------------------------------
  1   |  second      |  abc   | content  | editing <br />
  2   |  second      |  lcv   | content  | scripting <br />
  3   |  second      |  asd   | content  | finalize <br />
```

whenever i create new key suppose 'third' in multidimensional array the table will get generate automatically for that 'third' key also

so how i am going to achieve my desired output any help would be appreciated please help me thanks

Comment: You need to show us what you tried so far. This is not a tutorial site to get the basics explained.

Comment: $RowNumber=1; for ($row = 0; $row < count($arr1); $row++) {
        $cols = count($arr1[$row]);
        for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) {
       $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tbl_data;");
       
       while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '
         <td>'.$RowNumber.'</td>
         <td>'.$keyname.'</td>
         <td>'.$rows['Name'].'</td>
         <td>'.$rows['desc'].'</td>
         <td>'.$rows['dep'].'</td>';
         echo '</tr>';
         $RowNumber++;
        }
       }
      }

Comment: @04FS above code i have tried so far please check

Comment: Extended pieces of code are hardly readable in comments. Please edit this into the question instead (and format it properly.) And also give a proper _problem description_ - explain what you want the code to do, and how exactly it is not doing that.

Comment: i have added code what i had tried @ 04FS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an associative array and you can traverse it using `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ( $arr1 as $key=>$val) { 
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ( $val as $name){
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tbl_data where Name = $val;");
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            echo '<tr>'; 
            echo ' <td>'.$RowNumber.'</td>';
            echo ' <td>'.$keyname.'</td>';
            echo ' <td>'.$rows['Name'].'</td>';
            echo ' <td>'.$rows['desc'].'</td>'; 
            echo ' <td>'.$rows['dep'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        } 
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i really appreciate for your help the solution you provided is working well @CaffeinatedCod3r

Comment: I am glad that i could help. Happy Coding !!